# Convert .aspx page to Microsoft Excel Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

HI i want to use such thing in my web application that on a button click .aspx page converted in Xls page.
I did it but result is not good as I needed. I used this code on button click which is given below.

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        string filename = "TicketSecretary.xlxs";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        this.EnableViewState = false;
```

Comment: You don't actually tell us what's wrong with it.  More information is needed.

Comment: Shouldn't the extension be `xlsx` rather than `xlxs`?!

Comment: @archer its convert the page but two table are overlapping each other. Thanks

Comment: @sir Crispalot Yeah sorry but thats not the problem i have another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm missing the `Response.End();` at the end.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx